# Is the image formed at the retina messy?

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics

The following passage has been extracted from Newton's book Opticks:

> ...So if PR [in Fig.at the top] represent any Object without Doors, and AB be a Lens placed at a hole in
>   the Window-shut of a dark Chamber, whereby the Rays that come from any Point Q of that
>   Object are made to converge and meet again in the Point q; and if a Sheet of white Paper be held
>   at q for the Light there to fall upon it, the Picture of that Object PR will appear upon the Paper in
>   its proper shape and Colours....[image]
>   In like manner, when a Man views any Object PQR, [in Fig. at the bottom] the Light which comes from the
>   several Points of the Object is so refracted by the transparent skins and humours of the Eye, (that
>   is, by the outward coat EFG, called the Tunica Cornea, and by the crystalline humour AB which
>   is beyond the Pupil mk) as to converge and meet again in so many Points in the bottom of the
>   Eye, and there to paint the Picture of the Object upon that skin (called the Tunica Retina) with
>   which the bottom of the Eye is covered....

If we see the bluish sky with the high standing giant tall buildings, from the mountain, and analyse the validity of the above Newton's statements, it appears to be complex.

- Our eye lens is generally very small in comparison with the objects we look, and the diagram in the Newton's book doesn't seem to take concern about it. Isn't it?
- If we consider the above said situation of looking at the sky and a girl in the building, we can't expect all the rays of light of each single point of the girl or the building or the sky to come and converge in the methodical way to form the exact image of the object. The points of the objects can take a shift in the place and make messy image of the object. Isn't it?

This is what I understand with my analysis. So, is the image formed at the retina really messy?

Comment: Your argument isn't restricted to the eye. Aren't you arguing that **any** lens must produce a messy image? If not, what's unique about the eye?

Comment: The answer to that is simple: no, the image on the retina is no more "messy" than the image made on the film or CCD/CMOS sensor of a camera. What Newton could not know is that a healthy eyeball has an excellent optical performance for such a simple system. Technical lenses need much more complicated arrangements of optical elements to achieve similar performance. The reason for that is, that the image plane of the eye is curved, and that the gelatinous body inside the eyeball has a varying index of refraction, something which is very had to do with glass and optical sensors.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Yes, my argument isn't restricted to the eye.

Comment: @Godparticle: Then all you have to do, is to understand geometrically or algebraically, how a lens transforms an angle of an incoming ray to an almost proportional offset in its focal plane.

Comment: @CuriousOne: The question is not about how lens converges light.

Comment: "Messy" is not a useful or quantifiable term.  Are you asking about problems with "depth of focus," i.e. producing a sharp image of two objects at different ranges?

Comment: *By the figure drawn, we can't expect two or three rays (as that from point Q) to be converging at retina as Newton proposed* - **yes we can**. *We can expect single point (as like point Z) to be formed at two different locations of the retina at the same time* - **no it won't**.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Could you please be more explicit?

Comment: That's hard unless I write an answer explaining how a lens works. But there are already plenty of easily Googlable articles explaining how lenses work. What escapes me is why you think either of your statements is true. For example what calculations have you done to show that multiple rays from point Q don't all converge at a single point in the image plane?

Comment: @JohnRennie: I understood the little flaw in my question. I will reply if I still get any doubts. Thank you for your time and effort. Right now, I have deleted the confusing part to prevent more confusion.